# Adobe Flash fullscreen colours are shifted

Tags: windows-7, firefox, flash

This doesn't happen on all videos, it seems to be more of the lower quality videos than anything but still quite annoying. Only way I can describe the problem is that the colours shift about 100 pixels to the right in fullscreen mode, any help is greatly apperciated.

Anyway here are comparison screenshots of this video **youtube.com/watch?v=UPHuE5pDlEs**

### [Non-fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cZGl.jpg)

### [Fullscreen with shifted colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVrRp.jpg)

My specs and software versions:

> Adobe Flash Player 11.5.502.146

```
Windows 64-bit SP1, English 
Firefox 18.0.1 (Only enabled plugin is Flash)
```

> CPU: Intel Xeon E3-1230v2
>
> Graphics: Nvidia GT220 (Driver version 310.90)

Comment: Try disabling/enabling hardware acceleration. Look online for instructions on how to do this in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to check.

1. Have you recently cleared the flash player cache?
2. In order to clear, right click on the screen > Go to Local Storage option > Just drag the slider to left end and then a suitable position at the right area again. Or esls, use the online settings manager [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager03.html). In order to clear more thoroughly,  deselect "Store Common Flash Components To Reduce Download Times" and confirm the action. Then, select it back once again.
3. Clear browser cache.
4. If you suspect that Flash Player is experiencing issues, you can also try removing it with the recommended way and re-installing back. Guide can be found [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html).
5. If your video drivers depend on the Flash Player ActiveX for enhanced functionality, install Flash Player using Internet Explorer. Make sure the drivers are up to date.

Note: I tested myself with similar configuration (except the Graphics Device used), with no issues. If you are able to download the video, it is possible to play within, with the help of KMPlayer or s similar. If the issue you encounter is the same, there could be a problem with the installation of the Flash Player and/or drivers. To sort out the issue with Flash Player, you could install the debugger version of Flash Player (64bit). If you still require assistance, please feel free to comment.

Comment: 1. Yes   
2. I cleared it again using these instructions

3. Done

4. Done it before but I did it again this time and also deleted all folder/file traces of flash

5. Not sure about this since I don't use IE and don't intend on doing

`"If you are able to download the video, it is possible to play within, with the help of KMPlayer or s similar."`
I opened the youtube .flv URL and streamed it from VLC which worked fine in fullscreen.

Comment: 5 is just a fail safe option. You can download the same from http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/. The last comment clearly indicates that there is an issue with the Flash Player or browser itself. I also would like you to try the debugger version instead of the regular version. It can be obtained from: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.exe. Make sure there are no issues with hardware acceleration (turn off by opening Flash Player settings (left most option). Finally its the time to backup and re-install the browser and test again